# CSS overlap div over another div with a relative position / inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have an `<h3>` element which I need to keep at `width:100%` so it remains clickable from JavaScript I have, but at the same time, I need the description to be positioned on the right side of the title in one line instead of the next line which usually works fine with `display:inline-block`, but not while the title keeps 100% width, obviously pushing to a new line.

```css
h3.main.title {
    width:100%
}
.main.title {
    display:inline-block
}
.description {
    display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h3 class="main title">Category</h3>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kk5he25q/

Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Either you have to make it absolute or put some content in the h3 tag. 
Do you rely on the h3 tag or can it also be a div?

Comment: @jdickel I rely on it as its output of a drupal module and harder to change. What content do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to keep h3 at 100%, you can set the position of the description as absolute (don't forget to make the position of the parent div relative). However, keep in mind that h3 and description may overlap. See your updated jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kk5he25q/1/

```
h3.main.title{width:100%; position:relative;}
.main.title {display:block;}
.description{display:block; position:absolute;right:10px; top:7px}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried absolute but didn't manage and thought it won't work with scrolling the page?

Basically I have several of the whole lot underneath each other, FAQs to scroll through and expan to read.

I actually meant for description to be next to the title just a few pixel after. The challenge I have is the width of different titles varies.

Comment: If you want the description to show right after a title while the whole thing is clickable, try placing the description inside a span tag <span></span> and style it using CSS

Comment: I noticed you also moved my original description div element into the h3 element :) Thanks, I managed to adopt it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use float.

```css
h3.main.title {
  width: 100%;
}

.description {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p class="description">Description</p>
  <h3 class="main title">Category</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I needed it to show next to the category, not the right side of the page :) I figured floating won't work as it will have to attach to the h3 element. Wills answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this  ?

```css
*{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
.header {
    display: flex;
}

h3 {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px;
}

.description {
    padding:15px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h3 class="main title">Category</h3>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I needed the category on the left and description right next to it. 
Also, you missed the 100% width requirement on the h3 element. Thanks though.

Comment: so you want an element to be at 100% width, yet have more room to add something else next to it.

Comment: Yes, the h3 in me sample code. See the other answer from Will that worked. Cheers.